# Crear log de una tabla MySQL que depende de otra tabla mediante una clave foránea y tienen relación on delete cascade

Tags: mysql, trigger, delete

Tengo esta tabla en **MySQL**:

```
CREATE TABLE `USUARIOS` (
 `Correo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Contrasena` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Telefono` int(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Correo`),
 KEY `Correo` (`Correo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Y tengo esta otra tabla que se relaciona con la anterior mediante los campos USUARIOS.Correo = VIVIENDAS.Usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE `VIVIENDAS` (
 `IDVivienda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Usuario` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Transaccion` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IDVivienda`),
 KEY `Usuario` (`Usuario`),
 CONSTRAINT `VIVIENDAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Usuario`) REFERENCES `USUARIOS` (`Correo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Además tienen una relación **ON DELETE CASCADE**, de forma que cuando elimino un usuario, se eliminan también sus viviendas.

Tengo también para cada tabla una tabla **HISTORICO_NOMBRE_TABLA** con la misma estructura que su tabla original, donde guardo mediante un **trigger after delete** los datos que borro de cada tabla.

Mi problema es que al eliminar un usuario, se eliminan sus viviendas, pero no se me están guardando en la tabla HISTÓRICO_VIVIENDAS, si borro la vivienda directamente si que se me guardan en esa tabla. Por lo que deduzco que debo hacer un trigger específico para esto pero no sé como.

Añado los trigger para crear el histórico de cada tabla:

**Trigger AFTER DELETE** de la tabla **USUARIOS**

```
INSERT INTO HISTORICO_USUARIOS VALUES (old.Correo, old.Contrasena, old.Nombre, old.Telefono, date(now()))
```

**Trigger AFTER DELETE** de la tabla **VIVIENDAS**

```
INSERT INTO HISTORICO_VIVIENDAS VALUES(old.IDVivienda, old.Usuario, old.Transaccion, date(now()))
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La eliminación en cascada no activa los trigger de las tablas que tengas relacionadas, lo que pudieras hacer es dentro del trigger de usuarios buscar la vivienda relacionada y realizar el insert en el historico_viviendas